# Что означает данная строка кода (expression ? true: false)?

Tags: php

Добрый день!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что означает данная строка кода?

```
$imessage = $_GET['message']?$_GET['message']:false;
```

Comment: 'message' может отсутствовать в $_GET, поэтому лучше:

    $imessage = isset($_GET['message']) ? $_GET['message'] : false;

`isset` вернет TRUE, если есть ключ в массиве и по данному ключу в массиве есть значение.

Если необходимо проверить только наличие ключа, то лучше использовать:

    array_key_exists('message', $_GET)

array_key_exists вернет TRUE если в массиве (объекте) есть указанный ключ (аттрибут) (не проверяя наличие значения)

Сохранять значение (даже пустое) когда был передан параметр:

    $imessage = array_key_exists('message', $_GET) ? $_GET['message'] : false;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$var = TRUE;
echo $var==TRUE ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE'; // TRUE
echo $var==FALSE ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE'; // FALSE
```

А вообще в манах, всё написано!

Answer (score 6):

Добрый, чтобы не кидатся терминами это как бы if. **Синтаксис его такой:**
**Условие** ? **Если уровнение верное** **:** **Если уровнение не верное**

**По вашему примеру**:

```
if($_GET['message'])
   $imessage = $_GET['message'];
else
   $imessage = false;
```

**ВНИМАНИЕ!!** Если 2 и более условий требуются скобки (), иначе не чего хорошего не будет, скрипт будет работать не правильно.

Comment: Что в данном коде означают операторы "?" и ":" ?

Comment: Вам же предельно ясно объяснили. Почитайте уже про тернарный оператор наконец (http://goo.gl/fVMnN).

Comment: "Если 2 и более условий" - лучше уж использовать классические операторы ветвления, иначе получим нечитабельный код.